# mouse cursor for google maps overlays

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm creating a game based on google maps api v3 where the player has to guess some areas, by clicking on the right area on the map. But when I'm creating an invisible overlay the mouse cursor still changes from the open hand to the pointing hand, but it shouldn't change.
Is there a possibility to set the mouse cursor for overlays?
THX

Comment: Hi, I have exact same problem, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
...
var imageBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(35,25),
    new google.maps.LatLng(42,45)
);
var overlayOpts = {
    clickable: false
}
historicalOverlay2 = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
    'image.png',
    imageBounds,
    overlayOpts
);
...
```